# бот на библиотеке discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py, discord-api

от бота требуется переместить участника голосового канала в другой голосовой канал с именем "aab", но при попытке сделать это выпадает ошибка

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'`,

код бота:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '~')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game('перемещение'))
    print('Logged')
    #for member in client.get_all_members():
    #    print(member.name, member.id, member.activities)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def act(ctx, member: discord.Member, channel='id=aab'):

    await member.edit(voice_channel=channel, reason='none')
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть только строковое название канала. Чтобы переместить участника, нужно получить объект этого канала. Идеологически код должен выглядеть так, однако, вероятно, будет требовать отладки.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def act(ctx, member: discord.Member, channel_name='aab'):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.voice_channels, name=channel_name)
    await member.edit(voice_channel=channel, reason='none')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Аргумент `pass_context` в rewrite-версии discord.py не существует. Контекст всегда передаётся в функцию команды первым аргументом.
2. [`member.edit(voice_channel=Optional[discord.VoiceChannel])`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/api.html#discord.Member.edit) принимает объект типа `discord.VoiceChannel`, а не строку.
3. Используйте [конвертеры](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-converters) для получения подходящих объектов в аргументах команд.

```py
@client.command()
async def act(ctx, member: discord.Member, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
    print(channel.name, type(channel)) 
    # ~act user#0000 "Voice channel" →
    # Voice channel <class 'discord.channel.VoiceChannel'>
    await member.edit(voice_channel=channel)
```